# Path for embed in Twig cannot contain variables, else returns Variable not found error

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, twig, embed

For some reason, setting a variable to represent a file path, and then using that to embed does not work.  Does anyone know the reason?

This works:

```
{% embed 'Console::components/somecomponent' with {} only %}
{% endembed %}
```

But this doesn't:

```
{% set abc = 'Console::components/somecomponent' %}
{% embed abc with {} only %}
{% endembed %}
```

The above returns the following error:

Variable "abc" does not exist in "XXXXXX" at line 5.

---

On the other hand though, ironically, "include" seems to work as follows:

```
{% set abc = 'Console::components/anothercomponent' %}
{% include abc with {} only %}
```

---

If someone would be able to shed me some light I'd be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the "only"!

What will work is:

```
{% set abc = 'Console::components/somecomponent' %}
{% embed abc with {} %}
{% endembed %}
```

or:

```
{% set abc = 'Console::components/somecomponent' %}
{% embed abc %}
{% endembed %}
```

Comment: Or `{% embed abc with { 'abc' : abc }` only %}

Comment: Thanks @Basti, what you have advised is just a "workaround", because "only" needs to be there for other reasons.  But I think DarkBee has pinpointed the answer.

In fact this links tells us the reason: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2780

"The embed path is executed in the context of the embed template"